# Touchpad not working DELL Inspiron 15-3567

Tags: 18.04, touchpad

I have a problem with touchpad not working on my DELL Inspiron 15-3567. My Ubuntu is 18.04 LTS.
It started right after system update I have done on the 2nd of december 2019.

Notes from my `history.log`:

```
Start-Date: 2019-12-02  18:03:43 
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.148' 
Install: linux-modules-4.15.0-72-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-72.81, automatic), linux-headers-4.15.0-72-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-72.81, automatic), linux-headers-4.15.0-72:amd64 (4.15.0-72.81, automatic), linux-image-4.15.0-72-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-72.81, automatic), linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-72-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-72.81, automatic) 
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic:amd64 (4.15.0.70.72, 4.15.0.72.74), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.15.0-70.79, 4.15.0-72.81), linux-image-generic:amd64 (4.15.0.70.72, 4.15.0.72.74), libsqlite3-0:amd64 (3.22.0-1ubuntu0.1, 3.22.0-1ubuntu0.2), linux-signed-image-generic:amd64 (4.15.0.70.72, 4.15.0.72.74), linux-signed-generic:amd64 (4.15.0.70.72, 4.15.0.72.74), linux-generic:amd64 (4.15.0.70.72, 4.15.0.72.74) 
End-Date: 2019-12-02  18:06:30
```

Possible issues I have excluded so far:

- It's not hardware problem, as touchpad works perfectly in my BIOS.
- It's not a problem with old driver from Synaptics, I have checked it, and mine is the newest.

Comment: For now, use an external mouse or the previous kernel (4.15.0-70). See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1854798/comments/7 or read the [full bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1854798).

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exact same issue on my Dell Inspiron, Ubuntu 18.04. My current kernel version is 4.15.0-72-generic. I used Advanced Options for Ubuntu during boot and selected kernel version 4.15.0-58(generic).
The touch pad started working fine on doing that.

P.S.-I really have no idea why the touchpad works on -58 but not on -72.